# Should the badge list page be redesigned?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, badges

As the number of badges on Stack Overflow has grown I am noticing the /badges page is getting less and less usable.

Should the badges page be better organised? If so, how?

Comment: I don't know, is *usability* the real problem?  It isn't rocket science to look through a list.  Or does nobody ever look at it?  You've got the page hit counts, I suspect it is the latter.  I never look at it.  Just reminds me of badges I can never get :(  If you want to make the page more interesting then consider making it clear how close somebody is to getting a badge. That's a number that will change often enough to warrant a look.

Comment: I think the biggest problem is related badges are scattered -- Notable Question, Popular Question and Famous Question aren't together, and neither are Badges earned for questions, for answers, etc

Comment: Err.. doesn't "refactored" mean "changed internals without any observable change in behavior"?

Comment: I have posted a new blog entry to re-arrange the User Badges now http://bdgr.co/hYai3H

Comment: Just a heads up - we are currently redesigning the badges page and the privileges page for rollout in the next few weeks. It looks like all of the upvoted answers make sense and we'll probably incorporate those ideas in the final version.

Comment: @JeremyTunnell Any status on when this will happen?

Comment: @Doorknob This week for sure on the badge page.  Not a radical change, but I think we've addressed most of the complaints on meta.

Comment: @JeremyTunnell Yaaaay! `:D` Thanks `:)`

Comment: @Doorknob Badges refresh is live http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges

Comment: @JeremyTunnell Wow, that's amazing! Thanks :)

Comment: @JeremyTunnell - Looks beautiful!  Feedback posted here before I realized this post existed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184951/add-more-subgroups-to-the-participation-group-on-the-new-badge-page

Comment: @JeremyTunnell - the new Badges page did not apply to meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @JoshDM We currently have a massive amount of change sets backed up behind the close reasons, so we had to bypass meta for this one. Everything should be settled this week.

Comment: Cool. Just letting you know it's noticed for your TODO list if it wasn't there already.

Answer (score 28):

My initial thought would be to put them into an accordion widget, broken down into categories.

These are the categories I've got so far:

### Question Badges

- Altruist: First bounty you manually awarded on another person's question
- Benefactor: First bounty you manually awarded on your own question
- Famous Question(G):  Asked a question with 10,000 views
- Favorite Question(S): Question favorited by 25 users
- Good Question(S): Question score of 25 or more
- Great Question(G):   Question score of 100 or more
- Investor:    First bounty you offered on another person's question
- Nice Question: Question score of 10 or more
- Notable Question(S): Asked a question with 2,500 views
- Popular Question: Asked a question with 1,000 views
- Promoter:    First bounty you offered on your own question
- Scholar: Asked a question and accepted an answer
- Stellar Question(G): Question favorited by 100 users
- Student: Asked first question with at least one up vote
- Tumbleweed: Asked a question with no votes, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week

### Answer Badges

- Enlightened(S): First answer was accepted with score of 10 or more
- Generalist(S): Provided non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of top 40 tags
- Good Answer(S):  Answer score of 25 or more
- Great Answer(G):     Answer score of 100 or more
- Guru(S): Accepted answer and score of 40 or more
- Necromancer(S):  Answered a question more than 60 days later with score of 5 or more
- Nice Answer:     Answer score of 10 or more
- Populist(G): Answer outscored an accepted answer with score of more than 10 by more than 2x
- Reversal(G):     Provided answer of +20 score to a question of -5 score
- Revival: Answered more than 30 days later as first answer scoring 2 or more
- Self-learner: Answered your own question with score of 3 or more
- Teacher: Answered first question with score of 1 or more
- Tenacious(S): Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total
- Unsung Hero(G):  Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total

### Moderation Badges

- Citizen Patrol:  First flagged post
- Civic Duty: Voted 300 or more times
- Cleanup:     First rollback
- Copy Editor: Edited 600 entries
- Critic: First down-vote
- Disciplined: Deleted own post with score of 3 or higher
- Editor:  First edit
- Electorate: Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions
- Organizer: First retag
- Peer Pressure: Deleted own post with score of -3 or lower
- Sportsmanship(S): Up voted 100 competing answers
- Strunk & White(S): Edited 100 entries
- Suffrage: Used all 30 votes in a day
- Supporter: First up vote
- Tag Editor:  First Tag Wiki Edit
- Taxonomist(S): Created a tag used by 50 questions

### Participation Badges

- Autobiographer(B): Completed all user profile fields
- Beta(S): Actively participated in the Stack Overflow private beta
- Commentator: Left 10 comments
- Convention(S):   10 posts with score of 2 on meta
- Enthusiast(S): Visited the site each day for 30 consecutive days
- Fanatic(G): Visited the site each day for 100 consecutive days
- Precognitive:    Followed the Area 51 proposal for this site before it entered the commitment phase
- Pundit(S): Left 10 comments with score of 5 or more
- Quorum: One post with score of 2 on meta
- Talkative: Posted 10 messages, with 1 or more starred, in chat
- Yearling(S): Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation

### Other Badges

- Announcer:   Shared a link to a question that was visited by 25 unique IP addresses in 3 days
- Booster(S): Shared a link to a question that was visited by 300 unique IP addresses in 4 days
- Epic(S): Hit the daily reputation cap on 50 days
- Legendary(G): Hit the daily reputation cap on 150 days
- Mortardboard: Hit the daily reputation cap for the first time
- Publicist(G):    Shared a link to a question that was visited by 1000 unique IP addresses in 5 days

Comment: I kept them in alphabetical order here so it's easier to tell if any were missed, but if implemented it might be nice if related badges were grouped together by divs with colored background or something so it's easy to see the progression

Comment: Categories = good. Accordion widgets = frustrating :(

Comment: Code folding FTW!

Comment: @AdamDavis @bemace @renesis I think the solution here is something like the privileges design (also the way the Javascript Garden does things) (also I have inside knowledge of something forthcoming, a standard design concept they're already working on that is almost done)

Comment: They should implement this like the [faq redesign](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/newfaq) is being done ... Otherwise like this option suggests.

Answer (score 14):

The other option I thought of (for competitive voting goodness) would be a tabular format for the badges which come in Bronze/Silver/Gold flavors and leave the rest display like there are now.  This might make the badges less "exciting" to get though.

My crude mockup:
[image]

Comment: Since everyone's always wondering, you could even add a column showing how close people are to earning new badges

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to see different sorting options (tabs):

- alphabetic
- by color (gold/silver/bronze), like the linked [browser script](http://blog.codingbadger.com/post/Stack-Overflow-Badges.aspx) does.
- by group, as @[bemace](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/151987/bemace) suggested

Also, a button to **filter out achieved badges** would be awesome. Especially the "tags" badges page on SO is so crowded that you need a long time to find the badges you have.

What's also missing is a link to the detailled description of the tags on meta (i.e. [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/159560)) since the rules for badges are not always clear.

Comment: Yeah, doing something to filter out the ones we have or don't have would be cute, and if the divs are tagged in just such a way that will be easily done. Alternately, this can be done with a userscript afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

If this page is going to be redesigned, it would be nice to see how many people have the badge and how many times you have the badge on the same page. At the moment /badges is different from the badges section of your profile.

And if you're going to go crazy, for badges that can be awarded multiple times, tell me how many people have the badge that many times. Eg 411 people have Reversal on Meta (probably the easiest site to get it on - someone proposes something unpopular and you answer saying "I think this is a bad idea because" and bingo, gold badge) but how many have 2? 3? 11?

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, I'll go ahead and express the contrary opinion:

No, the badge list page is fine as it is (right now)

Comment: How is it fine? Maybe if you don't use it.

Comment: It's long-ish but I don't see a huge need to change it.  If anything maybe it indicates that we need to slow down on the creation of badges.  Now if the discussion was the *tags* badge page, I could see some room for improvement.