# Improve the badge page to filter by badge type

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges

Today I looked at https://stackoverflow.com/badges and wanted to see just Gold Badges, so I clicked on `Gold Badge` on the right side under the Legend heading. Nothing happened.

My suggestion is to make the buttons in the legend show only the type of badge you selected.

Comment: I mean I want to see all badges with choosen type. If I click on `Gold Bage` I want to see all Gold bages in list

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suggested improvements to badges index page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1980/suggested-improvements-to-badges-index-page)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting with the next build, we'll have filters on the badges page for "all", "gold", "silver" and "bronze" (defaulting to "all", same as the current view).

These filters will look/function like all other "sub-tabs" on other parts of the site (e.g. `/users`, your activity/reputation/responses profile views, etc.).

Comment: will there be a way to sort a user's badges?

Comment: @yoda - not in this push, we may take a look at it later on...a few other items on the plate this week.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote [a blog post](http://blog.codingbadger.com/post/Stack-Overflow-Badges.aspx) with some JavaScript to rearrange the badges in to Gold, Silver & Bronze sections.

<sub>Crappy code disclaimer: I know the JavaScript is nasty and I know my blog looks ..erm... different. Blog is a WIP and the JS works so I haven't bothered changing it :)</sub>

You might want to look at [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72744/should-the-badge-list-page-be-redesigned) posted by Waffles about the Badges page.

Answer (score 2):

The legend already appears to be active as a hover over Gold, Silver, or Bronze will highlight the badge.  However clicking does nothing.

I suggest that either the badges don't respond to the mouse (other than a tooltip), or to implement fl00r's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea of improving the badges page, if someone wants to target a specific badge I think it's useful to see which ones are most likely within grasp, so sorting by count sounds like a useful way to view the badges, I've created a bookmarklet for viewing them this way using the [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) plugin for jQuery...

```
(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://yourls.googlecode.com/svn-history/r332/trunk/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js",
        dataType: "script",
        success: function() {
            $("table .badge-cell").each(function() {
                $(this).before("<td class=\"count-cell\">" + ($(this).find(".item-multiplier").length > 0 ? $(this).find(".item-multiplier").html().replace(/[^\d.]/g, "") : "0") + "</td>")
            });
            $("#mainbar div table").prepend("<thead><tr><th></th><th class=\"count-cell\">Count</th><th class=\"badge-cell\">Badge</th><th>Description</th></tr></thead>").tablesorter({
                sortList: [[1, 1]]
            });
            $(".count-cell").css("width", "50px");
        }
    });
})();
```

results in a sortable table with headers (can click on the header to sort by that column):

[image: sortable badges table]