# Filter the badge list for gold, silver and bronze

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suggested improvements to badges index page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1980/suggested-improvements-to-badges-index-page)
>   [Improve the badge page to filter by badge type](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82145/improve-the-badge-page-to-filter-by-badge-type)

There is quite a long list of badges. Can we allow filtering the badges by category (gold, silver and bronze)?

Comment: [Also similar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82145/badges-page-improvement)

Comment: @Rob Hruska The first question you linked is about sorting the list of badges basing on the badge type; the second question is about the legend page.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - Actually, I just realized the first is for sorting on your actual profile page, so it's not a dupe. However, I think my second link is: it requests that if, on the badge page, you click the gold badge in the legend, that it only shows (i.e. filters) gold badges. That seems identical to what's being asked here.