# Badge Page "Legend" Categories activate but don't do anything

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges, user-interface

After reading [Improve the badge page to filter by badge type](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82145/improve-the-badge-page-to-filter-by-badge-type) was implemented, I went to the [Badges Page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges) and moused over "Gold Badge" in the "Legend" on the sidebar.

It activated / highlighted, but then when I clicked it, nothing happened. Then I realized I needed to click on the `gold` filter button above the badge list (like on other pages on the site, as [mentioned by Nick Craver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82145/improve-the-badge-page-to-filter-by-badge-type/106739#106739) in his announcement the feature was implemented).

The categories in the legend should either also be links to the appropriately filtered pages (my preference) or they shouldn't activate when you mouse over them, as this makes me think they're buttons.

Comment: More feature request than a bug, in my opinion..

Comment: @ShadowWizard I see it as a user interface bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This *would* be intuitive behavior, since you're used to clicking on badge doing *something*...so in the next build those legend links will trigger the same filters as the sub tabs does now.