# Badges are not synoptical - present them as hierarchy?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges

If you click "Badges" overview in menu or you see some users' badges, you just see a very, very long list which is not very synoptical. Wouldn't it be much nicer to present them in hiearchy? For example:

> Nice question  ->  Good question -> Great Question
>
> Notable question -> Popular question

In general, that could lead not only to a tree, but to more general acyclic graph - because one badge may be subset of more badges, but also two badges might be easiest version of one badge.

The badges could also be placed into groups, like

```
Answers
Questions
Promotion
Bounties
...
Funny
...
Other
```

That would be nice, wouldn't it? What are your ideas?

Comment: What? This crazy feature-request of mine is being considered? Wow! What solution are you thinking of, @JeremyTunnell?

Comment: Not a huge redesign, but we are going to do both progression and categorization. Maybe have something next week.

Comment: @JeremyTunnell, you mean classification like [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183714/166308)?

Comment: Like this one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72747/202998

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is one great idea. Although the present table is placed in alphabetical order, I feel that it does have its disadvantages, especially when it comes to groups, and categories, as Tomas has pointed out.

Putting them in groups, trees, and hierarchies would simplify matters a lot.

Great idea!

Answer (score 19):

I'd like to see a table with columns for bronze, silver and gold, and with badges that are "the same" in the same row. Rows should probably be grouped into categories, too.

[image]

Comment: This would really cry out for a `Tic-Tac-Toe` badge for getting three in a row.

Comment: Well, this would be only possible if the hierarchy tree is simple, but in general each badge could have more "upgrade" badges than just one. And maybe the upgrade badges need not to follow the bronze-silver-gold line exactly (what if there is some bronze-silver-silver-gold or something like that?). Somebody should do the analysis first, i.e. build the complete hierarchy tree.

Comment: that is a great idea :)

Answer (score 2):

I think that, in case this were to be modified, the user should be able to select the display. Similar to the list of answers ...

[image: answer display]

... that has four options to customize it, the badge display (which currently lists newest first I think) could look something like this:

[image: badge display]

But ...

I think the hierarchical display will not be as easy to implement as changing the order from newest to alphabetical would be. Plus, this kind of display will definetly make the badge list a lot longer. For example, if one has 3000+ badges like [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) (to pick one arbitrarily :)), the list would get a lot longer since you'll never display more than three badges per "row".

Also, what would be the display behavior for badges that don't have three versions, like *Autobiographer*, *Beta*, *Commentator*, *Cleanup*, ...? Are they going to be listed on a single row for themselves, or rather en-bloc below the hierarchical display similar to the way things are right now? The former would prolong the display even more ...