# Add additional sub-groups to the new Badge page & related Feedback

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges, information-display

On the [newly redesigned Badge page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) (A+), there are sub-groups under the major groups.  For example, the Participation Badges group has related badges Commentator and Pundit sub-grouped, and Quorum and Convention sub-grouped.

I am of the opinion at least 1 of the following additional sub-groupings should be made:

#### Question Group

- Student & Scholar
- Investor & Altruist
- Promoter & Benefactor

  - Alternately, one sub-group of Investor, Altruist, Promoter & Benefactor

#### Answer Group

- Teacher, Enlightened, Guru
- Consider moving Generalist to Tag Badges Group or the bottom of the Answer Group if Tag Badges is moved immediately below Answer Group.

#### Participation Group

- Talkative & Outspoken
- Caucus & Constituent
- Precognitive & Beta

#### Tag Badges

Move this group to either the bottom of all groups or below the Answer Group. Its current placement here creates a weird artificial barrier, especially with users who have no Tag Badges.

#### Moderation Group

- Informed & Analytical
- Taxonomist & Synonymizer
- Critic & Supporter
- Disciplined & Peer Pressure
- Suffrage, Vox Populi & Civic Duty

  - Alternately, one sub-group of Critic, Supporter, Suffrage, Vox Populi & Civic Duty
- add Cleanup and Organizer to the Editor sub-group
- add Citizen Patrol to the Deputy sub-group

**NOTE:**
Since this is now **status-completed**, but only a select portion was completed, the rest of the request has been broken into 2 additional questions:

1. [Create Badge Sub-Groupings based on Sibling relations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188246/create-sub-groups-for-sibling-badges-on-the-badge-page)
2. [Move the position of the Tag Badge Group](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187047/move-the-tag-badges-category-to-immediately-after-answer-badges-on-the-badges-pa)

Comment: This is exactly what I was wondering :P

Comment: I think a similar request, badge-chaining, is [meta-tag:status-planned]

Comment: @AsheeshR - I was unable to find the specific request you mention.

Answer (score 2):

The sub-groups that are currently live on the new badges page are only for badges that build off of each other - they are meant to show that you can earn additional badges if you progress in the same activity that earned you the bronze badge. There are a few in your suggestions that make sense (talkative and outspoken, for example), but some of the groupings you propose don't actually build off of each other (scholar and student, for example - they're both bronze badges, and there is no particular order of events you must follow to earn them both).

Additional combinations might make sense if they follow the existing rationale behind the sub-groups (i.e., show progression), but we shouldn't have two types of groupings with different logic behind each.

Comment: Following the sub-group "build off of each other" logic, we have: Talkative and Outspoken; Citizen Patrol, Deputy and Marshal; Suffrage and Vox Populi. Who can update the content of the page?

Comment: That's not accurate for Revival and Necromancer: you can't progress from the first to the second with the same answer, and you can earn Necromancer without earning revival (if your answer was not the first). So they don't exactly build off of each other, but still make sense to be visually grouped together.

Comment: Do note I requested at least one of the proposed groupings; not necessarily all of them, and I expect the comment area to be a mild debate as to which are worthy. While I recognize the initial volley of sub-groupings focused on the low-picked fruit of progression, other sub-groupings of perceived progression exist (of which Revival/Necromancer belongs) and should be grouped. For example, Disciplined & Peer Pressure (both Bronze) are polar opposites, but from a "scoring" observation, which is what the Badges! reward system is, they are obvious siblings and should be grouped as such.

Comment: For the reasons stated by Laura, we're going to group your three suggestions from the participation group. We can't quite make the case that the rest of them make sense as a progression.

Comment: Why restrict to progression when siblings are obvious?

Comment: Part of the reason I requested this is also to aid the sorting of the badges; right now they are alphabetic, which is OK except the groups flow into the middle of the alphabetic lists, which creates a break in alpha flow and generates visually unappealing lone badges.

Comment: @JeremyTunnell - Constable and Sheriff are not progression, yet they are grouped.

Comment: @JoshDM Unfortunately, we have so many different kinds of badges that it is virtually impossible to hold to a strict standard of grouping. You're completely correct, but I would also say that these *should* be grouped. We're basically down to making decisions on a case-by-case basis. So the general rule is progression, but sometimes we break it on the margin.

Comment: While you wrote that, I wrote another question because I once read here that proposing another question and chancing that it will be flagged duplicate rather than just eating one's own tail is preferred.

Comment: @JeremyTunnell - added links to two other questions which handle the unimplemented portions of this now status-completed question.