# Sportsmanship, Informed and Analytical appear under "Moderation" on new badges page?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, badges

On the new badge page (which is nice, btw) there are a couple of things I'm not sure about - for example everything is split up into sections grouped by the type of badge in question, so "Favourite Question", "Investor" and "Tumbleweed" all appear under a heading "Question Badges", "Enlightened", "Revival" and "Reversal" appear under a heading "Answer Badges", etc...

However, the "Moderation Badges" section includes the badges "Analytical" - a badge for reading the FAQ, "Informed" - a badge for reading the about section, and "Sportsmanship", a badge for voting on other people's posts on questions where you have a positively scored answer. I'm not sure that these badges belong here.

Starting with the first two, these would probably be better suited under the "Other Badges" heading, but regarding Sportsmanship, is voting actually a moderation privilege? Would it be more suited to having a "Voting Related Badges" sub-section with all of the voting related badges ("Electorate", "Vox Populi", etc) contained under it?

---

As a quick side note, since I don't think it's worth raising a seperate question over it - the two tags "Disciplined" and "Peer Pressure" should also probably be grouped together under "Moderation", currently they're both under "Moderation" but in seperate sub groups.

Comment: got breakdown of several subgroup proposals here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184951/add-additional-sub-groups-to-the-new-badge-page-related-feedback

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have moved Analytical and Informed to the "Other" category.

Sportsmanship will remain under Moderation as we do not currently plan to separate out the voting badges from the Moderation section. Ultimately, voting is a moderation privilege granted in the same way flagging and editing and closing are.