# Why are some related badges not grouped in the Badges Page?

Tags: discussion, badges

I have seen that the [badges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) has recently been updated. I like the way this was done, but some related badges are not grouped, like these:

First bountys:

- Altruist
- Benefactor
- Investor
- Promoter

First Questions:

- Scholar
- Student
- Tumbleweed

Messages in chat:

- Outspoken
- Talkative

Flagged posts:

- Deputy
- Marshal
- Citizen Patrol

Used x votes in a day:

- Suffrage
- Vox Populi

Why is that so? Could these be grouped, like some others are?

Comment: possible dup: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184951/add-additional-sub-groups-to-the-new-badge-page-related-feedback

Comment: I cast the last vote to close this question as a dupe, but please feel free to post your suggested groupings as an answer to the question linked at the top. That way, you can still get feedback about those suggestions (see also my answer there about keeping the same logic for all sub-groups).