# Move the Tag Badges category to immediately after Answer Badges on the Badges page

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, badges, help-center

Currently, the Badge Categories on the [Help Center > Badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) are ordered in a non-alphabetic, semi-arbitrary manner, likely based on utility.

1. Question Badges
2. Answer Badges
3. **Participation Badges**
4. **Tag Badges**
5. Moderation Badges
6. Other Badges

Tag Badges are derived from providing Answers.  The order suggests Tag Badges are more related to participation than answering questions.  I recommend moving the Tag Badges category to immediately after Answer Badges.

Suggested Order:

1. Question Badges
2. Answer Badges
3. **Tag Badges**
4. **Participation Badges**
5. Moderation Badges
6. Other Badges

This suggestion [was originally posed here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184951/add-additional-sub-groups-to-the-new-badge-page-related-feedback), but likely was lost in the noise as it was never addressed in any answer.

Comment: And apparently this one is lost in the noise too because I just got awarded my first Tumbleweed Badge ever.

Comment: +1, not only are tag badges more related to answer badges, but also participation badges are more related to moderation badges. No big deal, but I guess it's a 2-min fix, so worth it.

Comment: This seems reasonable to me. I've passed this request up the chain. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is a bad idea; however, the developer who's been leading this feature is moving on to a new project, and we unfortunately can't make infinite tweaks.