# Create sub-groups for sibling Badges on the Badge page

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, badges, help-center

Most of the badge sub-groups on [the Badge Page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) are grouped based on direct progression (bronze, silver, gold).  Some, including Constable and Sheriff, are sub-grouped based on a perceived relationship, hereafter referred to as siblings.  They may not have direct progression, but are logically related.

[The parent request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184951/add-additional-sub-groups-to-the-new-badge-page-related-feedback) of this question was tagged as status-completed, which is why I've created this question.  While some sub-groups proposed in the parent were created, others were denied with the reason being there was no direct badge progression.  Many of the denied could be considered siblings.  Unlike the parent request, **this request provides direct rationale behind any requested sibling badge sub-groups.**  This is not a duplicate of the parent.

Siblings, and their grouping rationales are:

#### 1) Investor (Bronze) / Benefactor (Bronze)

- Investor is the first bounty you offer on your own question.
- Benefactor is the first award of any bounty you offered on your own question.

  - cannot be earned without first earning Investor

#### 2) Promoter (Bronze) / Altruist (Bronze)

- Promoter is the first bounty you offer on someone else's question.
- Altruist is the first award of any bounty you offered on someone else's question.

  - cannot be earned without first earning Promoter

#### 3) Teacher (Bronze) / Enlightened (Silver) / Guru (Silver)

- Teacher is (1) answering and (2) receiving 1 up-vote.
- Enlightened is (1) first / fastest to answer, (2) accepted answer, (3) 10 up-votes

  - cannot be earned without first earning Teacher
- Guru is (1) accepted answer, (2) 40 up-votes

  - cannot be earned without first earning Teacher

While Guru and Enlightened are not progressive with each other since Enlightened requires one to be the first answer:

1. grouping both with Teacher is sensible.
2. Guru and Enlightened are too similar not to be grouped.

#### 4) Supporter (Bronze) / Critic (Bronze) / Suffrage (Bronze) / Vox Populi (Bronze) / Civic Duty (Silver) / Electorate (Gold)

- Supporter: first up vote

  - polar opposite of Critic; direct sibling
- Critic: first down vote

  - polar opposite of Supporter; direct sibling
- Suffrage : Used 30 votes in a day

  - cannot be earned without earning either Supporter or Critic; progression
- Vox Populi : Used the maximum 40 votes in a day

  - cannot be earned without earning Suffrage; direct progression
- Civic Duty : Voted 300 or more times

  - cannot be earned without earning either Supporter or Critic; progression
- Electorate : Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions

  - cannot be earned without earning either Supporter or Critic; progression

All relate to voting and there is some form of progression involved, if not necessarily directly. If listed in this order, if nothing else, it would help to organize the current disorganized appearance of the Moderation Group.

### Rejects

I will not argue for the following (non-)sibling groups proposed in the earlier request, but there is at least one differentiation request:

#### Scholar (Bronze) / Student (Bronze)

While both regard asking questions and both Badge names reference education, Scholar is about asking, then accepting an answer; Student asks a question and receives an up-vote.  If anything, the descriptions should be differentiated; Scholar could be reworded to *"First acceptance of an answer to your own question."*

#### Synonymizer (Bronze) / Taxonomist (Silver)

While both are orphan badges related to tags in a very large group, I'm not married to having them grouped.

Comment: Electorate also needs Civic Duty.

Comment: @hjpotter92 - Not necessarily.  You can earn Civic Duty by voting 300+ times on Answers.  That's why I didn't list it like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea has merit, but unfortunately we're reaching a point where we have to stop making changes to the help center for the time being. We've done our best to address most of the feedback we've received, but we likely won't be making any more changes to the help center for the near future; our lead developer for this feature is moving on to a new project.